# how do I assign values from text file to a structure of arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have to do an election program in C.

There are 7 candidates and 365 votes in total. I need to do this using an array of structures. I need to read from a text file each of the names of the candidate and the number of votes they get. At the end i need to output the winner of the election.

Here is a sample of my code so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct candidates {
        char name[20];
        int votes;
    };


    int main()

     {
        //Counter
        int i = 0;
        int gVotes = 0;
        //Votes counter
        int v = 0;
        //Sploit Vote
        int spVote = 0;

struct candidates electionCandidate[7];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
      char * aNames = fgets(electionCandidate[i].name, 20, fp);
    }

//for testing each candidate gots their name
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. Candidate is %s\n\n", i+1, electionCandidate[i]);
    }  
 //For 365 Votes

 while (!feof(fp))
       {
            int iVoteFor = 0;
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &iVoteFor);
            electionCandidate[iVoteFor-1].votes++;
            //gVotes is my counter for the number of entries. 
            printf("%d ", ++gVotes);
        }

        system("pause");

        return 0; 
    }
            //Ideas of what to use
```

Here is my current elections.txt

```
Robert Bloom
John Brown
Michelle Dawn
Michael Hall
Sean O’Rielly
Arthur Smith
Carl White


3 3 81 1 2 3 1 2 4 5 
1 6 12 9 6 5 0 2
8 46 6 8 3 2 8 0 12 6 1 8 
3 11 7 5 5 8 9 10 12 1 3 12 
2 23 2 5 7 4 11 8 6 11 12 
9 11 7 9 3 1 2 10 12 
12 7 11 9 6 6 0 1 10 7 11 2 8 
0 12 8 10 11 2 2 8 4 2 12 3 2 9 1 
4 88 7 7 4 12 2 10 10 9 4 12 9 3 12 
0 48 0 6 5 9 0 5 3 11 6 0 3 0 1 2 3 
4 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 8 4 5 
9 1 2 12 1 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 7 1 2 
4 5 1 2 3 1 2 8 7 12 95 41 1 7 5 4 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7
7 8 8 9 9 8 7 7 1 1 2 3 5 4 4 6 8 7 52 1 4 7 
5 2 5 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 7 7 7 1 2 5 4 7 8 7 4 1
4 7 8 7 4 1 5 2 5 2 3 6 5 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 
2 2 5 1 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 2 1 
3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 4 5 8 1 2 4 1 4 2 5 
6 7 8 1 2 3 3 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 1 2 3 4
```

EDIT:

Each candidate gets +1 vote for their number electionCandidate[0] for each one he gets one vote and so on for the rest. 365 voters in total.

I was able to input the name for each Candidate from the text file. Now the problem is putting each vote to the corresponding candidate. Also any vote that is above 7 is a spoilt vote which i am trying to count in the above code.  The code compiles but it crashes.

I am using  while(!feof) but it seems that its not working or this is not the correct way. Any suggestions.

EDIT:
I am using the debugger and find that it runs for a few times around the      while(!feof)
but in one of the instances it gives the error and stops.

EDIT: 
By commenting out the line     electionCandidate[iVoteFor-1].votes++; the program reads all the way to 365 value.

how do I assign each to vote to each candidate?

Comment: Please don't use `void main()`, even on Windows where it is supported.  The correct return type is `int`, and on C89 systems (such as Microsoft's compilers), you should include `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: you need to add the name of the `FILE*` btw

Comment: 1) `22` in `fgets(electionCandidate[i].name, 22, fp);` when `sizeof electionCandidate[i].name == 20`?  2) Do not use `feof()`, use the return value from `fscanf()`.   3) Code is not testing for spoiled votes.

Comment: Code does a big non-no with `while (!feof(fp)) { ...}`.  The `fscanf()` _before_ `feof()` became true failed to read any votes and so `iVoteFor` remains at 0.  Code does no range checking and then proceeds to do `electionCandidate[0-1].votes++;` which is outside `electionCandidate[]` --> Oops.  Curious: what reference suggested using `feof()`?

Comment: !feof doesnt that read the contents of the entire file that i am reading from? I saw this being used in another post

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct candidate
{
    char name[20];
    int votes;
};

enum { MAX_CANDIDATES = 7 };

static int vote_cmp(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{
  int votes1 = ((const struct candidate *)vp1)->votes;
  int votes2 = ((const struct candidate *)vp2)->votes;
  if (votes1 < votes2)
    return -1;
  else if (votes1 > votes2)
    return +1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct candidate electionCandidate[MAX_CANDIDATES];

  char buffer[4096];
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0; i++)
  {
    if (strlen(buffer) < 2)
      break;  // Blank line
    if (i >= MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Too many candidates: %s", buffer);
      return 1;
    }
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);
    if (len >= sizeof(electionCandidate[i].name))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Candidate name too long: %s", buffer);
      return 1;
    }
    memmove(electionCandidate[i].name, buffer, len - 1);
    electionCandidate[i].name[len] = '\0';
    electionCandidate[i].votes = 0;
  }

  size_t n_cand = i;
  int spoiled = 0;
  unsigned votefor;
  while (scanf("%u", &votefor) == 1)
  {
    if (votefor == 0 || votefor > n_cand)
      spoiled++;
    else
      electionCandidate[votefor-1].votes++;
  }

  qsort(electionCandidate, n_cand, sizeof(electionCandidate[0]), vote_cmp);

  for (i = 0; i < n_cand; i++)
    printf("%20s: %3d\n", electionCandidate[i].name, electionCandidate[i].votes);
  putchar('\n');
  printf("%20s: %3d\n", "Spoiled votes", spoiled);

  return 0;
}
```

Given the sample data, with the quote in Mr O'Rielly's name modified from UTF-8 to ASCII, the output is:

```
    Arthur Smith:  17
   Sean O'Rielly:  21
   Michelle Dawn:  33
      John Brown:  36
    Robert Bloom:  39
    Michael Hall:  40
      Carl White:  64

   Spoiled votes:  77
```

Clearly, "Spoiled votes" is the duly elected winner.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read strings from file, you need to use fgets rather than fscanf since fgets reads the whole string. So reading of strings should look like:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    // initialize everything to zeroes
    // otherwise they should be initialized manually in a loop
    struct candidates electionCandidate[7] = {0}; 
    FILE *file = fopen("elections.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
    {
        char * res = fgets(electionCandidate[i].name, 100, file);

        printf("%s\n", res);
    }

    //strcpy(electionCandidate[0].name, "Daniel Guzman");
    //electionCandidate[0].votes = 41;

    //printf("%s got %d Votes\n\n", electionCandidate[0].name, electionCandidate[0].votes);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Reading the votes and counting will look like this:

```
while (!feof(file))
{
    int iVoteFor = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &iVoteFor);
    electionCandidate[iVoteFor-1].votes++;
}
```

I believe it's easy to find the winner afterwards.

Comment: I dont quite understand how you electionCandidate[iVoteFor].votes is working here since each candidate is has a number associated with them for example "1" number is saying i am voting for the first one in my list. how is this telling it that.

Comment: Ok. There was a bug. Now it's `electionCandidate[iVoteFor-1].votes++`, which means the following. The number associated is the index of the candidate, so you take the record, corresponding to the candidate index, get the vote number for this index (which is 0 after initialization) and increase it for 1 with operator ++;

Comment: "1" number is saying i am voting for the first one in my list, so this is the first record. However, C start counting from 0, this is why "iVoteFor-1" indexing.

Comment: the line     electionCandidate[iVoteFor-1].votes++; when i put this line it displays the correct output but the program crashes i keep trying to format it in a different way but my program crashes

Comment: Why use 100 instead of OP's 20 or better yet `fgets(electionCandidate[i].name, sizeof electionCandidate[i].name, file);`?

Comment: Use of `while (!feof(file)) ...` is wrong.  Use the return value form `fscanf()`.

Comment: I think it's impossible to teach one all the trade tricks at once. So we need to start from something simple. Your comments are correct, but the quite outside the scope of the simple homework.

Comment: I read up on fgets realizing that instead of 22 i can just put 20 since that is the limit of     Char[20]

Comment: Now, when you got it, you can use `char * res = fgets(electionCandidate[i].name, sizeof(electionCandidate[i].name), file);` instead of 22 or 20 or any number

Comment: How can I do this now for the Candidates Votes for each and count each vote++ for each candidate?

Comment: If you want me to teach you about C/C++, mark this answer as answer. ))

Comment: any ideas for my   for(v=0;v<365;v++) it compiles without

Comment: You don't need this `for(v=0;i<365;v++)` as you're reading all the votes until the end of the file no matter how many. If you want specifically 356, you need to remove `while(!feof)` and leave just `for(v=0;i<365;v++)`

Comment: I see because while(!feof) goes through my file. Even when i take it out my program still crashes. Complies without errors but when attempting to read the votes it crashes. Im stock any hints. electionCandidates[iVoteFor-1].votes++; how do i ++ the number of votes each person gets?

Comment: Probably your file doesn't actually have such amount (365) of votes. Try to add `printf("%d ", ++i);` into your reading loop and see which record causes crash. Another consideration, do you set number of votes to zero initially?

Comment: I get an output that starts with 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ........... to 35 thats the output i get. I used   for(v=0;v<7;v++)
  {
   electionCandidate[i].votes = 0;
  } to initialize all votes for each candidate and now the output does not even show up. my elections.txt files has 365 digits seperated each by a space for example     4 7 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 in this example candidate 5 should have 4 votes and be the winner.

Comment: get an output that starts with 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ........... to 35 thats the output i get. I used for(v=0;v<7;v++) { electionCandidate[v].votes = 0; } to initialize all votes for each candidate My elections.txt files has 365 digits seperated each by a space for example 4 7 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 in this example candidate 5 should have 4 votes and be the winner. Now im an infinite loop within the while(!feof)

Comment: If you get to 35, it means you have just 35 numbers and you want 356 and continue to read after the file is ended

Comment: In your code `electionCandidate[v].votes < 8` someone gets more than 8 and file pointer doesn't move anymore. so `feof` is always `false`

Comment: yes i realized that after debugging some more now i am using if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &iVoteFor) < 8) but it only outputs 8 9 then it crashes

Comment: Don't inlcude logic in reading. Just get all the votes first and then process the electionCandidate in another loop

Comment: by "dont include logic" i am interpreting it as dont do the If ELSE statement now. Just get the values in and then do the IF ELSE For assignment. I still have the printf("%d ", ++i) statement and it prints from 8 9 10 11 ................ to 39 now then crashes.

Comment: Lat time it was 35, now 39. If it's constant or different numbers every time? It's getting hard to evaluate the problem without seeing the code and data.

Comment: I edited my code to exactly what i am doing now and i also show the input file elections.txt could this file be the problem the way my numbers are put?

Comment: my code can read up to the 32th value but if i go to the text file and change one number to another number it reads to 39 i think it cant read my file for some reason.

Comment: I was able to read the 365 numbers from the file by commenting out the line electionCandidates[iVoteFor-1].votes++

Comment: Thank you for removing the answer.