# Program Crash when Reading from File

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct candidate
{
char candidateName[20];
int votes;
};



Initialize()
{
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
    FILE* ifp;
    int i;
    struct candidate electionCandidates[7];
    ifp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
    {
        strcpy(electionCandidates[i].candidateName, "aaaaa");
        electionCandidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        memset(&firstname[0], 0, sizeof(firstname));
        memset(&lastname[0], 0, sizeof(firstname));

        fscanf(ifp, "%s %s", &firstname, &lastname);
        strcat (firstname, " ");
        strcat (firstname, lastname);
        strcpy (electionCandidates[i].candidateName, firstname);
        printf("%s", electionCandidates[i].candidateName);
    }


}

int main()
{
    Initialize();
    return(0);
}
```

The above code is supposed to read first and last names from a file, and add them to the candidateName portion of the struct. When I run this program, it assigns and prints the begginning first and last name, but then immediately crashes.

The file is in the format of

```
first last

first last

first last
```

etc

I feel like this may have something to do with it not going to read the next line, but I do not know how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `firstname` only allocates enough space for 9 characters plus the terminating NULL character.  Is it possible that `firstname` + space + `lastname` is longer than that?

Comment: Seems like lots of people have the same homework today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691729/how-do-i-assign-values-from-text-file-to-a-structure-of-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

**Problem 1**

The line:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%s %s", &firstname, &lastname);
```

is a problem if the first name and/or the last name in the input file is longer than 9 characters.

To take care of that problem, specify the maximum number of characters you want to read. Also, from a type point of view, use `firstname` instead of `&firstname`.

```
fscanf(ifp, "%9s %9s", firstname, lastname);
```

**Problem 2**

The lines

```
strcat (firstname, " ");
strcat (firstname, lastname);
```

is a problem if length of `firstname` + length of `lastname` is greater than 8.

You can use:

```
strcpy (electionCandidates[i].candidateName, firstname);
strcat (electionCandidates[i].candidateName, " ");
strcat (electionCandidates[i].candidateName, lastname);
```

to solve that problem.